# LINQ Lambda Where() not filtering as expected

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to build a query using LINQ for EF to filter results based on some basic logic. For some reason, even with the following Where() functions being executed and setting the right parameters, all data is being returned instead of the filtered results from Where().

I have run debug to make sure that my if() statements are indeed allowing the Where() to run when appropriate, and it is.

What am I missing?

```
var dbReports = db.SubmitReports;

if (Referee != String.Empty)
    dbReports.Where(u => (u.Refree == Referee || u.Ar1Official == Referee || u.Ar2Official == Referee || u.FourthOfficial == Referee));

if (TeamName != String.Empty)
    dbReports.Where(u => (u.HomeTeam == TeamName || u.VisitingTeam == TeamName));

if (PlayedOnStart != DateTime.MinValue && PlayedOnEnd != DateTime.MinValue)
    dbReports.Where(u => (u.PlayedOn >= PlayedOnStart && u.PlayedOn <= PlayedOnEnd));

if (StateAssociation != String.Empty)
    dbReports.Where(u => (u.StateAssociation == StateAssociation || u.StateAssociation2 == StateAssociation));

if (Division != String.Empty)
    dbReports.Where(u => u.Division == Division);

if (ProfessionalLeague != String.Empty)
    dbReports.Where(u => u.ProfessionalLeague == ProfessionalLeague);

if (AgeGroup != String.Empty)
    dbReports.Where(u => u.AgeGroup == AgeGroup);

return dbReports.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where doesn't *modify* the existing query - it creates a *new* query. You need to assign the result of the call to Where to something otherwise the result is simply discarded. Try this:

```
IQueryable<Report> dbReports = db.SubmitReports;

if (...)
{
    dbReports = dbReports.Where(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never use the return value of the Where method.  Where does not modify the IEnumerable it is apply on but returns a Linq expression that will create a modify IEnumerable when executed (i.e when ToList is called).